# How to show collapsed elements in CoordinatorLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

I have `CoordinatorLayout` as described in blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              ...
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

     <TextView
              ...
              app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Inside `AppBarLayout` I have `Toolbar` and `TextView` with additional status info. `AppBarLayout` can be collapsed (after scrolling). Sometimes I need to show `AppBarLayout` in order to show changed status.

How to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As mentioned in [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137264/2232889):

> Using support libs v23 you can call `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true/false)`

Comment: why this is not accepted as answer? works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Due to answear from [Tuấn Trần Anh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151811/tu%E1%BA%A5n-tr%E1%BA%A7n-anh), founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30747281/3735097), you can use this two methods to collapse and expend `CoordinatorLayout` programaticly:

```
public void collapseToolbar(){
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
    if(behavior!=null) {
        behavior.onNestedFling(rootLayout, appbarLayout, null, 0, 10000, true);
    }
}

public void expandToolbar(){
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
    if(behavior!=null) {
        behavior.setTopAndBottomOffset(0);
        behavior.onNestedPreScroll(rootLayout, appbarLayout, null, 0, 1, new int[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i use this solution

```
 public void resetAppBarLayout() {
    if (mContentContainer != null) {
        final AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior container_behavior = ((AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior)
                ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mContentContainer.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior());
        if (container_behavior != null) {
            container_behavior.setTopAndBottomOffset(appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());
        }
        final AppBarLayout.Behavior appbar_behavior = ((AppBarLayout.Behavior)
                ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).getBehavior());
        if (appbar_behavior != null) {
            appbar_behavior.setTopAndBottomOffset(0);
        }
    }
}
```

for force showing appbarlayout. Reset scrolled view to appbarLayout max scroll range and appBarLayout to start position = 0.