# Collapsing toolbar animation doesn't move

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml, android-toolbar

I was implementing the collapse toolbar in my app , it should be all right but the bar is not restricted .. does not move does nothing !!!

This is my layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_button_margin_right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my activity

```
    public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
    int mutedColor = R.attr.colorPrimary;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.anim_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Hello!");

        ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.background);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        if(fab != null)
            fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

                mutedColor = palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
                collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimColor(mutedColor);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

please tell me why , thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
I've solved the problem with NestedScrollView, i do something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarAction"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- List of something -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_button_margin_right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/user"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/testPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any actual scrolling content? The toolbar collapses based on the scrolling child of the `CoordinatorLayout` with `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: @karaokyo no .. you say to use a RecycleView with app:layout_behavior ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `RecyclerView`, you could also use a `NestedScrollView`

Comment: I've never heard of, what would it be?

Comment: It passes back information to its parent via callbacks such as `onNestedScroll`, which is what allows the toolbar to respond to its scroll events.

Comment: have you an example ?

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: @karaokyo However I tried to insert a recycle view but nothing .. nothing changes, it is as if it were blocked

Comment: Well, I guess it's lucky that you have a full working example...

Comment: @karaokyo not full example but for understanding the operation of NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this it works for me, also you can add any view inside AppBarLayout under the toolbar to animate up and  down with toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/coordinatelayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can change ViewPager to any view just add its behavior, Also you can check Bartosz Lipinski answer if your want to animate it programmatically 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655939/android-programmatically-collapse-or-expand-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_weather">


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="georgeoikonomou.fishing.CurrentWeatherFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_weather"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:background="#5863e3"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="#e23c7f"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:title="adas"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```