# Can CollapsingToolbarLayout fit the image height?

Tags: android, height, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

Is it possible to set the height of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` or `AppBarLayout` when the image is already loaded? Similar to Whatsapp behaviour.

Whatpsapp behaviour (Conversation Info Activity):
The `AppBarLayout` height containing the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is set on activity creation to a fixed value. But, when the group image is loaded, you can scroll to see the image on full height.

**Edit**: The target is fitting the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the image, getting the same proportion, and avoiding image crop.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655939/android-programmatically-collapse-or-expand-collapsingtoolbarlayout might be of some help

Comment: @Nishant It is not about expanding programmatically, but fitting the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with the image, getting the same proportion, and avoiding image crop.

Comment: I think you can do the same thing if you know the image height and width. You can set the imageview to image height and programatically collapse the toolbar accordingly to some specific value. So a user can expand a toolbar if he wants.