# Android: Programmatically Collapse and expand the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android

I have ImageView and TabLayout(4 Tabs) inside CollapsingToolbarLayout, Now i want to collapse Appbar when clicking on Tabs(2,3,4) and for first tab it should work normally(as per scrolling). Is there a way to expand and collapse Appbar programmatically?

however i have seen [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655939/programmatically-collapse-or-expand-collapsingtoolbarlayout), appBarLayout.setExpanded(false) collapses Appbar but again it is able to drag down. i want to prevent AppBar Expansion until **Tab 1** is clicked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true)` to expand `Toolbar` and use `mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false)` to collapse `Toolbar`.

> If you want to prevent **CollapsingToolbarLayout** expansion until
>   **Tab 1** is clicked then you should use `mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params)` programmatically to change
>   `CollapsingToolbarLayout` height.

**Collapse:** Use when `Tabs(2,3,4)` clicked

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 3*80; // COLLAPSED_HEIGHT

mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
```

**Expand:** Use when `Tab 1` clicked

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) mAppBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 3*200; // EXPANDED_HEIGHT

mAppBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
```

Hope this will help you~