# Toolbar collapses on click of button in List Item

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am using `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBarLayout`, So i am facing problem that is when i click List Item Button toolbar collapse.

It is working fine with till Support Library `com.android.support:design:24.1.1` but it start giving problem when i update it.

Here is the XML code i am using

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff6600"
    app:elevation="6dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_view_tabs"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tabs_view_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is [Image link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/acvwo75039t6ij9/stackOver_img.jpg?dl=0) for better understanding of problem

So help me out in this if i am doing something wrong or its a library bug.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30655939/703851

Comment: @VaibhavA.Jani it does solve the problem as I need to expand toolbar everytime when button is clicked so can it be solved by changes in xml