# How to apply state collapsed in coordinator layout on touch

Tags: android

[Coordinator layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9tKu.png)

Hello, I have this coordinator layout and two autocomplete textviews.
I want to collapse the collapsing toolbar whenever the user will touch on any autocomplete textviews.
How will I do that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655939/programmatically-collapse-or-expand-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: If you past your code, it should be really much simple for me to ask your question

Comment: @Radhey I tried that but its not working,I guess I'll try again!